# Que se escriba la tecla que pulso en el textbox

Tags: c#

Me gustaria saber como puedo hacer que al precionar una tecla en el textbox, me muestre que tecla presione, por ejemplo:
presiono la tecla "espacio" en el textbox y quiero que dentro muestre "space", si presiono la tecla "a" se borre el "space" y muestre "A".
No quiero que se pueda escribir un texto en el textbox, no se si se entiende , quiero que me muestre solamente y unicamentela letra que tipee

Comment: si entiendo bien lo que queres hacer, lo  unico que queres tenes que hacer es el space, lo otro lo unico que tenes que hacer es que  sea Mayuscula

Comment: En el evento `KeyDown` del textBox puedes usar `e.KeyCode.ToString();` así obtienes el nombre de la tecla presionada.